# Redis Instance in Azure Seems to delete keys automatically

Tags: azure, redis, jedis, azure-redis-cache, redis-cli

We are trying to benchmark performance of Redis in Azure. To that end, we created a Premium Tier Redis node in Azure, and are trying to put simple Key-value pairs.

We have tried both Jedis and Redis-cli. When we are actually running these, we are able to query the Keys already populated, but once the process completes, values for all Keys are returned as null. Even

```
redis-cli -h {host} -p 6379 -a {password} keys "*"
```

returns empty list.

Any ideas as to what might be wrong here?

Comment: When you put the keys in, what TTL do you set?

Comment: I'm not setting TTL explicitly. Also, I'm not using any weird setting in Azure for Redis. Everything is set to default value.

Comment: Can you check if the process you're talking about is not flushing the database once it completes?

Comment: Hi Gaurav, That did the trick. Thanks.

Comment: @D159 Have been the issue resolved?